# Discrepancy in sources of the complement of the Borromean rings?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, manifolds, hyperbolic-geometry, knot-theory

I was going through Bill Thurston's "The Geometry and Topology of 3-Manifolds" (specifically Ch. 7: http://library.msri.org/books/gt3m/PDF/7.pdf). Along with Wikipedia (which uses it as a source), it mentions that the complement of the Borromean rings are homeomorphic to 2 ideal octahedra glued together. However, I watched the video "Not Knot," which claims that the complement of the Borromean rings is homeomorphic to a rhombic dodecahedron. I am inclined to believe Thurston, however I came across https://www.ias.edu/ideas/2016/agol-hyperbolic-link-complements, which was written by Ian Agol. It shares a rendition of the complement of the Borromean rings, which seems to be an ideal version of a rhombic dodecahedron (if that is a thing). Are these two things the same thing? If not, what is their relation or why the discrepancy?

Comment: There is no contradiction between the two claims. Aside: It is not true that the complement "is" [what you wrote]. The correct claim is that the complement is homeomorphic to the space obtained by particular gluing of some hyperbolic polyhedra using hyperbolic isometries.

Comment: Sorry about that, I have a hard time with precision in language, but yes, I did mean homeomorphic. I'm not sure why there is no contradiction. Could you elaborate on why?

Comment: For example, a torus is homeomorphic to a square with opposite sides glued together, and it is also homeomorphic to a hexagon with opposite sides glued together. Certainly there is no contradiction in this.